# Bash appending extra characters to variable?

Tags: bash, centos7, docker-container

I'm trying to store values in variables and trying to echo result to a file. But when it's adding two variables and echoing it to a file, extra characters are being added to the output file. This is happening in docker container, Can some one please help...

```
IFS=" "
#while read line
while read c s e
do
    echo $c $s $e
    first=$(echo "PER_${s}_${e}")
    #echo -n $first
    second=$(echo "/IPD_${c}")
    #echo $second
    echo $first$second >> /mnt/resource/step2/messages.txt
done < /mnt/resource/step2/job_control/Categories.txt
```

Categories.txt contains :

```
129490 201515 201540
```

I'm getting the output as :

```
PER__/IPD_PER_201515_201540/IPD_12949029490
```

But it should be like:

```
PER_201515_201540/IPD_129490
```

Comment: Your script outputs `PER_201515_201540/IPD_129490` in my system. What if you delete the file `messages.txt` and run again your script?

Comment: Can you please show the output of `head -2 Categories.txt | od -c` to verify your field separator?

Comment: Hi @ghoti, this is the output for your command.  
     `root@df435:/mnt/resource/step2/job_control# head -2 
     Categories.txt | od -c
     0000000   P   E   R   _   2   0   1   4   0   6   _   2   0   1   5   0
     0000020   5   /   I   P   D   _   1   2   9   4   9   0  \r  \n   P   E
     0000040   R   _   2   0   1   4   1   0   _   2   0   1   5   0   9   /
     0000060   I   P   D   _   1   2   9   4   9   0  \r  \n
     0000074`

Comment: You have `\r` at the end of your source lines, which is not a character that `read` will strip, and will cause the output you're seeing since the cursor "returns to the start of the line" when it is read, so either have code that expects and handles `\r` or use a tool like `dos2unix` to get rid of them

Comment: Hi @EricRenouf, thanks that's a useful tip to use dos2unix to get rid of hidden characters.

Comment: @Arunkumar, are you sure? That looks more like your output data, not your input data. Also, could you edit your question and add things there? Comments do terrible things to formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, but your code is more complicated than it needs to be.

```
while IFS=" " read c s e; do
    first="PER_${s}_${e}"
    second="/IPD_${c}"
    echo "$first$second" >> /mnt/resource/step2/messages.txt
done < /mnt/resource/step2/job_control/Categories.txt
```

Comment: Yeah; I think I meant to match the OP's use of `do` on the next line by itself; then forgot to type it.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it is more complex but I used your code and still it is producing the same output.